# Hi I am learning about angularjs. I want to get the TEMP from one json and display that value in my component. I dont konw what I am doing wrong

Tags: angularjs, rest, fetch-api, openweathermap

I m learning js fetch.
I am trying to get the value of temp from a respons and display that value in my component.js

### weather.component.js

````
```    
    myApp.component('weatherComponent', {
        template:"<p>Weather: {{vm.weather}}</p>",
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: function WeatherController($scope,$element, $attrs) {
          vm = this;


          var apikey = "";
          var city = "London";


          fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid=" + apikey)
          .then(function(response) {
            vm.weather = response.main.temp;
            console.log("weather: "+ vm.weather);
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(myJson) {
            console.log(myJson);
          });

        }
      });
```
````

### index.html

````
```
<weather-component></weather-component>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
<script src="weather.component.js"></script>
 ```

In utils it is initialized var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
````

The API Response url: https://openweathermap.org/current

---

Comment: My AngularJs days are far behind me, but it seems to me you need to use arrow functions to have access to the outer scope inside your then. So do .then((response) =>  { vm.weather = response.result // or something instead of using the function keyword

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the element from the json:

> `controller.weather = response.weather[0].description;`

2. The way to reolve this:
   create a service, so I could get the data & change the component.
   I discard the idea about to use "fetch".

### weather.service.js

````
```myApp.service('weatherService', function($http, $q) {
    this.getWeather = function (apikey, city) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // HTTP call
        $http.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid=" + apikey)
            .then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(response){
                deferred.reject(response);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
 ```
````

### weather.component.js

````
``` 
 myApp.component('weatherComponent', {
  template:"<p>Weather: {{weather}}</p>",
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: function WeatherController($scope, weatherService, $element, $attrs) {
      var apikey = "b441194a96d8642f1609a75c1441793f";
      var city = "London";
      var controller = $scope;
      controller.weather = "None";
      weatherService.getWeather(apikey, city).then(function(response) {
          controller.weather = response.weather[0].description;
      });
  }
});
 ```
````